How to display images in Angular version 18.2.6?
Using angular version 18.2.6 (note: there are previous SO threads, but none that apply to this version).
I have a standalone component NavbarComponent that I want to include an image on. The HTML for the component:
<mat-toolbar class="toolbar">

    <a routerLink="/">
        <img src="" alt="IPCC Logo">
    </a>

      <a routerLink="/">
        <span style="font-size: 20px">Inpatient Psychological Care Collaborative (IPCC)</span>
      </a>
    
      <div class="spacer"></div>

      @if (true) {
        <ul id="nav-items">
          <li><a routerLink="/mission">Mission & Values</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/about">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/listserv">Listserv</a></li>
        </ul>
      }

</mat-toolbar>

...and the TS for the component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    MatToolbarModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrl: './navbar.component.css'
})
export class NavbarComponent {

}

The image is stored in /src/assets/images/logo.png, however does not display when the code is compiled, as shown below:

How do you display local images within an Angular V.18.2.6 app?
Update #1
angular.json file:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ipcc": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ipcc",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/azure-blue.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "1MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "4kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "ipcc:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "ipcc:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/azure-blue.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


The assets directories are configured in angular.json. By default you either have a public or an assets directory at the root of your project which should contains the assets.

@MatthieuRiegler just updated w/ the contents of my angular.json file. If I put the image inside the /public folder then refer to it in my img src attribute by ../../../../public/logo.png, it still does not display the image.

The src should be relative to the destination at build. public/logo.png

@MatthieuRiegler unfortunately that doesn't fix it either. Still shows the alt text of the image with <img src="public/logo.png" alt="IPCC Logo">. Any other ideas?

my bad, drop the public, the content of public will be at the root of the dist. So for you src="logo.png"
